# Why does my recursive (non tail) implementation of quick-sort NOT cause a stack overflow? Using Common Lisp, SBCL

Tags: recursion, common-lisp, stack-overflow, compiler-optimization, sbcl

I was planning to change this function to avoid stack-overflow, but my recursive and non-tail call optimized implementation doesn't seem to overflow, and I don't know why. The largest array I tried had 10 million elements.

```lisp
(sort-array-from-to (random-array 10000000) (lambda (a b) (- b a)) 0 1000000)
```

I'm using SBCL to run my Common Lisp code from SLIME. Here is my implementation:

```lisp
(defun sort-array-from-to (xs cmp-fn beg end)
  "Quick-Sort just the elements of the simple array XS from BEG idx to
just before END using CMP-FN. The CMP-FN should return an integer < 0
to indicate <, 0 for =, and n > 0 for >."
  ;; TODO convert to cps trampoline to avoid stack overflow  
  (when (<= (- end beg) 1) (return-from sort-array-from-to xs))
  
  (let ((pivot (partition xs cmp-fn beg end)))    
    (array-swap xs beg pivot)
    (sort-array-from-to xs cmp-fn beg pivot)
    (sort-array-from-to xs cmp-fn (1+ pivot) end)))

(defun array-swap (xs i j)
  "Destructively swap elements of array XS at I and J"
  (let ((tmp (aref xs i)))
    (setf (aref xs i)
          (aref xs j))
    (setf (aref xs j)
          tmp))
  xs)

(defun partition (xs cmp-fn b j)
  "Used in quicksort. Returns idx of new pivot point after partitioning XS destructively."  
  (let ((pivot-val (aref xs b))
        (i b))
    (loop until (>= i j) do      
      (incf i 1)
      (loop until (or (= i (1- j))
                      (< (funcall cmp-fn
                                  (aref xs i)
                                  pivot-val)
                         0))
            do (incf i 1))
      (incf j -1)
      (loop until (or (= j b)
                      (> (funcall cmp-fn
                                  (aref xs j)
                                  pivot-val)
                          0))
            do (incf j -1))
      ;; If j get to b and every j is >= pivot-val, the pivot should stay put.
      (when (= j b) (loop-finish))      
      (when (< i j)        
        (array-swap xs i j)))
    j))
```

**UPDATE**
The program worked for an array of size up to 1 million, and it took less than a minute. I would think that would be more than enough to cause stack overflow no? But for 10 million, I checked on SLIME after a while and it said "Lisp disconnected". I don't know if that could be caused by stack overflow.

Comment: The SBCL compiler does TCO. Thus the tail calls in your code are optimized.

Comment: My Lisp skills are minimal, but assuming your pivot selection isn't terrible, the max recursion depth should be about log2( N ) which is only 23.25.  Even with imperfect but not worst-case pivot selection, that's probably only 24 to 30 levels of recursion.  With a Windows or Linux process getting a 1 MiB or 8 MiB callstack by default, that's plenty.  (I don't know how SBCL handles the Lisp call-stack, if it's different from how a C compiler makes functions that use the normal asm stack, but regardless a depth of about 30 is pretty trivial, especially without many local variables in each frame)

Comment: If you want to see stack overflow, maybe try intentional worst-case pivot selection, like choosing the first element of the range for an already-sorted or reverse-sorted array.  (In the double-recursive `sort-array-from-to`, the second call can get optimized as a tail-call, but the first one probably not, so you want the first of the two calls to be the one that gets all-but-one elements to sort.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a comment says, the recursion depth goes logarithmically with the size of the array assuming non-awful pivot selection.  That means you need really enormous arrays to run into stack overflow problems.

I modified your code like this:

```
(defun sort-array-from-to (xs cmp-fn beg end depth depther)
  "Quick-Sort just the elements of the simple array XS from BEG idx to
just before END using CMP-FN. The CMP-FN should return an integer < 0
to indicate <, 0 for =, and n > 0 for >."
  ;; TODO convert to cps trampoline to avoid stack overflow  
  (funcall depther depth)
  (when (<= (- end beg) 1) (return-from sort-array-from-to xs))
  
  (let ((pivot (partition xs cmp-fn beg end)))    
    (array-swap xs beg pivot)
    (sort-array-from-to xs cmp-fn beg pivot (1+ depth) depther)
    (sort-array-from-to xs cmp-fn (1+ pivot) end (1+ depth) depther)))
```

And then wrote these two:

```
(defun random-array (n)
  (let ((a (make-array (list n) :element-type 'fixnum)))
    (dotimes (i n a)
      (setf (aref a i) (random most-positive-fixnum)))))

(defun depth (n)
  (let ((a (random-array n))
         (d 0))
    (sort-array-from-to a (lambda (a b) (- b a)) 0 n
                        0 (lambda (depth)
                            (setf d (max depth d))))
    (dotimes (i (1- n))
      (unless (<= (aref a i) (aref a (1+ i)))
        (error "unsort")))
    d))
```

And now you can check what the depth is.  It's obviously a little variable but it empirically appears to be about ~2.5 log(n) where n is number of elements.

Incidentally your `array-swap` should just be `rotatef`.